# why controls in updatepanel disappeared?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have two UpdatePanel(tvUpdatePanel and tvResultUpdatePanel) on one page, as you can see in the image, the first UpdatePanel contains a text box and a button, the second updatepanel contains three GridViews below(For designing purpose, i have to put these two parts seperately). I've set both UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to "Always". I encountered a strange thing: when clicking "next page" of the gridviews or the "search" button, the three Gridviews will disappear from the page. I have to click the "Tailored View" tab then the GridViews show again. The next page or search function are working well. Why is this happening? How to fix this? Thanks!
[image]

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="tvUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="TailoredViewTab" style="display: normal">
                            <%--<uc4:TailoredView runat="server" id="TailoredView" />--%>
                            <div class="div_options" style="margin-top: 10px; font-style: italic;">
                                Complete code search criteria below and click <b>SEARCH</b> button.
                            </div>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="geographicalAreasDropDownList" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="20px"
                                Style="display: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 5px"
                                DataSourceID="geographicalAreaSqlDataSource"
                                DataTextField="Description"
                                DataValueField="ID" />
                            <ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hme4ga" runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="geographicalAreasDropDownList"
                                PopupControlID="gaHoverPanel"
                                PopupPosition="Bottom"
                                HoverDelay="0"
                                OffsetX="0"
                                OffsetY="10"
                                PopDelay="0">
                            </ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="newsAreasDropDownList" runat="server" Height="20px"
                                DataSourceID="newsAreasSqlDataSource"
                                DataTextField="Description"
                                DataValueField="ID"
                                Style="display: none; margin-left: 60px; margin-top: -15px" Width="200px" />
                            <ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hme4na" runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="newsAreasDropDownList"
                                PopupControlID="naHoverPanel"
                                PopupPosition="Bottom"
                                OffsetX="0"
                                OffsetY="10"
                                PopDelay="0">
                            </ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tvSearchTbx" runat="server" Text="" Height="20px" CausesValidation="true"
                                onkeypress="return UserPressKeyOnTVTB(event);"
                                Style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -20px" Width="650px" />
                            <ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hme4st" runat="server"
                                TargetControlID="tvSearchTbx"
                                PopupControlID="stHoverPanel"
                                PopupPosition="Bottom"
                                OffsetX="20"
                                OffsetY="10"
                                PopDelay="0">
                            </ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender>

                            <span class="btn_wrap span_margin_left10">
                                <asp:Button ID="tvSearchBtn" runat="server" CssClass="input_btn" Height="20px" Style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 100px;" Text="Search" OnClick="tvSearchBtn_Click" />
                            </span>
                            <%--<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="tbxValidator" runat="server" Style="position: relative; margin-left: 250px; margin-top: 25px; color: #FC890D; font-size: large" ErrorMessage="* Incomplete search request - Please complete all search criteria." ControlToValidate="searchTextBox"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>--%>
                            <div runat="server" id="errorMessageDiv" style="margin-top: 50px; display: none; height: 40px; width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: x-large; color: #FC890D">
                            </div>

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="geographicalAreaSqlDataSource" runat="server"
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RDSConnectionString %>"
                                SelectCommand="STP_GetGeographicalAreas"
                                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="newsAreasSqlDataSource" runat="server"
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RDSConnectionString %>"
                                SelectCommand="STP_GetNewsAreas"
                                SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="progress" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100" DynamicLayout="true">
                                    <ProgressTemplate>
                                        <img src="img/LoadingTailoredView.gif" alt="Loading data, please wait..." />
                                    </ProgressTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdateProgress>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="tvResultUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="TailoredViewResultTab" style="display: none">
                        <div id="TopicCodesGridViewDiv" class="RoundCornerDiv" style="background-color: transparent; position: relative; display: normal; width: 30%; height: 250px; top: 30px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 33%">
                            <div id="TopicCodesLabelDiv" style="height: 20px; margin-top: -53px; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; display: normal; text-align: center; font-size: large; color: #ff6a00">
                                <asp:Label ID="TopicCodesLabel" runat="server" Class="label">Topic Codes</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <asp:GridView ID="TopicCodesGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="TopicCodesResult"
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="TopicCodesGridView_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                OnPageIndexChanging="TopicCodesGridView_PageIndexChanging"
                                Style="margin-top: 3px; table-layout: fixed; max-width: 100%;"
                                OnRowDataBound="TopicCodesGridView_RowDataBound"
                                AllowSorting="True"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div>
                                                <%#Eval("Code") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridViewLeftAlign">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="tailoredViewGridViewRight" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                                                <%#Eval("Description") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <%-- <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Button" Visible="true" />--%>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#FC890D" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FC890D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Width="50px" />
                                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#FC890D" />
                                <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
                                <RowStyle Width="150px" BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FC890D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Green" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                            </asp:GridView>

                        </div>

                        <div id="treeViewDiv" class="RoundCornerDiv" style="margin-top: auto; position: relative; display: normal; width: 30%; height: 250px; top: -346px; margin-left: 33%; margin-right: 33%">
                            <div id="treeViewLabelDiv" style="margin-top: -53px; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; display: normal; text-align: center; font-size: large; color: #ff6a00">
                                <asp:Label ID="treeViewLabel" runat="server" Class="label">Topic Tree View</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tvTreeViewDiv" class="TailoredViewScroll" style="margin-top: 3px; text-align: left; overflow: scroll; height: 290px;">
                                <ul id="tvTreeView" class="filetree">
                                    <li>
                                        <span title="title" class="folder">Folder0</span>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li title="This is child 0">
                                                <span class="file" style="color: red">Child 0</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="file" title="This is child 1" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 1</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 2" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 2</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 1">
                                                <span class="file">Child 1</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 4" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 4</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 5" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 5</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 2">
                                                <span class="file">Child 2</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="file" title="This is child 1" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 1</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 2" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 2</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 3">
                                                <span class="file">Child 3</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 4" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 4</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is child 5" style="visibility: visible">
                                                <span class="file">Child 5</span>
                                            </li>
                                            <li title="This is folder 2">
                                                <span class="folder">Folder 1</span>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li title="This is folder 2's child 1">
                                                        <span class="file">child child 00</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li title="This is child 4" style="visibility: visible">
                                                        <span class="file">Child 4</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li title="This is child 1">
                                                        <span class="file">child child 01</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li title="This is child 4" style="visibility: visible">
                                                        <span class="file">Child 4</span>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <span class="folder">Folder 2</span>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <span class="file">file 0000</span>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <span class="file">file 0000</span>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>

                                        </ul>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="RecurringReportsGridViewDiv" class="RoundCornerDiv" style="position: relative; display: normal; width: 30%; height: 250px; top: -722px; margin-left: 66%">
                            <div id="RecurringReportsLabelDiv" style="margin-top: -53px; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; display: normal; text-align: center; font-size: large; color: #ff6a00">
                                <asp:Label ID="RecurringReportsLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" Class="label">Recurring Reports</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <asp:GridView ID="RecurringReportsGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="RecurringReportsResult"
                                Style="margin-top: 3px; table-layout: fixed; max-width: 100%;"
                                OnRowDataBound="RecurringReportsGridView_RowDataBound"
                                AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Code">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div>
                                                <%#Eval("Code") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridViewLeftAlign">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="tailoredViewGridViewRight" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                                                <%#Eval("Description") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#FC890D" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FC890D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px" />
                                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#FC890D" />
                                <PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
                                <RowStyle Width="150px" BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </div>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CompanryRicsResult" runat="server"
                            TypeName="TR.News.RDWS.SearchTool.DataManager.DataManagerRepository"
                            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                            SelectMethod="GetCompanyRics4TailoredView"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="TopicCodesResult" runat="server"
                            SelectMethod="GetTopicCodes4TailoredView"
                            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                            TypeName="TR.News.RDWS.SearchTool.DataManager.DataManagerRepository"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="RecurringReportsResult" runat="server"
                            SelectMethod="GetRecurringReports4TailoredView"
                            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
                            TypeName="TR.News.RDWS.SearchTool.DataManager.DataManagerRepository"></asp:ObjectDataSource>

                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="gaHoverPanel" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#FC890D">
                            Select primary geographical area of interest
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#FC890D" ID="naHoverPanel">
                            Select primary news area of interest
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="stHoverPanel" CssClass="hoverMenu4TailoredView" ForeColor="White" BackColor="#FC890D">
                            Enter keywords in English that relate to your news area of interest
                        </asp:Panel>

                        <div id="CompanyRicsGridViewDiv" class="RoundCornerDiv" style="display: none; width: 30%; height: 550px; top: 30px; margin-left: 0px">
                            <div id="CompanyRicsLabelDiv" style="margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 20%; text-align: center; display: normal; font-size: large; color: #ff6a00">
                                <asp:Label ID="CompanyRicsLabel" runat="server" Text="Label" Class="label">Company RICs</asp:Label>
                            </div>
                            <asp:GridView ID="CompanyRicsGridView" runat="server" OnDataBound="CompanyRicsGridView_DataBound" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="CompanryRicsResult"
                                Style="table-layout: fixed; max-width: 100%;"
                                OnRowDataBound="CompanyRicsGridView_RowDataBound"
                                AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderStyle-Width="30%" ItemStyle-CssClass="tailoredViewGridViewLeft" DataTextField="RIC" HeaderText="RIC" SortExpression="RIC" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="#CompanyTab">
                                        <HeaderStyle Width="30%" />
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="tailoredViewGridViewLeft" />
                                    </asp:HyperLinkField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridViewLeftAlign">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="tailoredViewGridViewRight" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                                                <%#Eval("Name") %>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ControlStyle Width="250px" />
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="gridViewLeftAlign" />
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FC890D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Width="50px" />
                                <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" />
                                <%-- <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="repFooter" OnItemCommand="repFooter_ItemCommand" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <div class="pager"></div>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="gridViewPager" >
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkPage" BackColor="Green" ForeColor="Red" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' CommandName="ChangePage" 
                                CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </PagerTemplate>--%>
                                <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#FC890D" />
                                <RowStyle Width="150px" BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                            </asp:GridView>`enter code here`
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: fix the snapshot, and post the code

Comment: Snapshot fixed, code posted. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by move the tvResultUpdatePanel inside the outter "display:none" Div.